# can i use function "sort by" in function read_csv if i want to ort dataframe based on a column?

Tags: python, pandas

Can i include sorting function in "read_csv" function if i want to sort the dataframe based on a particular column? Here in this dataframe I want to sort by a column named "Date" which has date values

uptill now I was using the sort_values function seperately.

```
df1=pd.read_csv('RELIANCE.csv')
df1=df1.sort_values(by='Date')
```

Comment: No, it is not possible in pandas in `read_csv` function.

Comment: As @jezrael said it's not possible. If you want you can chain methods.

Comment: Can you explain how to chain?

Comment: `df1 = pd.read_csv('RELIANCE.csv').sort_values(by='Date')`

Comment: yes of course, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can i include sorting function in "read_csv" function if i want to sort the dataframe 
>   based on a particular column?

It is not possible in pandas function `read_csv`, only you can chain methods:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('RELIANCE.csv').sort_values(by='Date')
```

Also you can convert column `Date` to datetimes:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('RELIANCE.csv', parse_dates=['Date']).sort_values(by='Date')
```